# python take a number of letters out of a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list called `colors` and I want a player to pick 4 colors and then I want them to be saved to a variable after the player has chosen these colors this is my code so far I cannot figure out how to make the 4 colors that the player has chosen to become a variable.

```
colors = ['R','Y','G','B','P','O']

print ("player 1 Create a 4 color code using", colors)
print "player 2 look away!!"
p1code = raw_input(">>> ")

if p1code == len(colors):
    print "i got the code now!"
```

Comment: `len(colors)` is 6, while `p1code` is a string from the user; you might want to think a bit more about what you're trying to achieve before putting it to code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need brackets in some of your `print` calls and you want `input` rather than `raw_input`, if you're using Python 3.

```
colors = ['R','Y','G','B','P','O']

print("player 1 Create a 4 color code using", colors)
print("player 2 look away!!")
p1code = input(">>> ")

if p1code == len(colors):
    print("i got the code now!")
```

Otherwise, with Python 2.x, you don't need brackets, and it will probably help you avoid bugs if you're consistent (currently on your first `print` line you also print the brackets `('player 1 Create a 4 color code using', ['R', 'Y', 'G', 'B', 'P', 'O'])`:

```
colors = ['R','Y','G','B','P','O']

print "player 1 Create a 4 color code using", colors
print "player 2 look away!!"
p1code = raw_input(">>> ")

if p1code == len(colors):
    print "i got the code now!"
```

Secondly: You have stored the four colours in `p1code`. When I run the above code:

```
player 1 Create a 4 color code using ['R', 'Y', 'G', 'B', 'P', 'O']
player 2 look away!!

RBGY #what I entered

In [9]: p1code
Out[9]: 'RBGY'
```

Thus you can see the string `'RBGY'` is stored in the variable `p1code`.

Comment: Python 2 `raw_input()` is Python 3 `input()` ([don't want `input` if using Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4915366/5358968))

Comment: You make a good point, I saw brackets with `print` and assumed Python3.